# Adding decorators (similar to spell check underline) to Word using Interop

Tags: ms-word, office-interop

I have a word document and I'd like to allow the user to highlight the content controls when they hover over a piece of text in a custom task pane. I can highlight the word I alter the font of the content control but I'd like to be able to do it without my actions appearing on the undo stack.
I could of course clear the undo stack but this is not desired behavior either.
Is there any way to create a highlight that is not part of the document but just gets attached to a bit of text/picture/content control like spell checker does?